# Scoring Ping Pong in Elixir

Tags: beginner, elixir

I have some elixir code I am using to score a ping pong game. Since I am new to functional programming I was hoping there might be a more elegant solution to this.

This part of the code is used in a GenServer to check if the next point could result in a win. So that means will the leading players next point meet the minimum score requirement (11 or 21 in ping pong) and also be 2 points in front of the other play.

Anyone got a better idea here?

```
def handle_call(:next_point_wins, _from, game) do
#game.score = [10,5]
nextPlayer1 = List.first(game.score) + 1
nextPlayer2 = List.last(game.score) + 1

scoreDifference =
  case nextPlayer1 > nextPlayer2 do
    true
      ->
      leader = nextPlayer1
      nextPlayer1 - nextPlayer2
    false
      ->
      leader = nextPlayer2
      nextPlayer2 - nextPlayer1
  end

cond do
  scoreDifference + 1 >= 2 and leader >= game.winningScore
    ->
      IO.puts "SOMEONE IS ABOUT TO WIN"
      {:reply, :ok, game}
  true 
    -> 
      IO.puts "NO-ONE IS ABOUT TO WIN"
      {:reply, :ok, game}
end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things you could do to improve this code:

#### Don't assign inside a case statement.

You assign a value to `leader` inside this case statement:

```
scoreDifference =
  case nextPlayer1 > nextPlayer2 do
    true
      ->
      leader = nextPlayer1
      nextPlayer1 - nextPlayer2
    false
      ->
      leader = nextPlayer2
      nextPlayer2 - nextPlayer1
  end
```

Support for this is deprecated in Elixir, and I assume will eventually be removed.  The Elixir compiler will complain about this when it sees it, and you should listen to it.  Generally you should find a different way to express this.  One option is to return a tuple from your case:

```
{scoreDifference, leader} =
  case nextPlayer1 > nextPlayer2 do
    true -> 
      {nextPlayer1 - nextPlayer2, nextPlayer1}
    false -> 
      {nextPlayer2 - nextPlayer1, nextPlayer2}
  end
```

#### Use if when appropriate.

A `cond` statement that has one branch with conditions and one `true` branch is basically just an if statement.  So it'd be simpler to just use an `if`:

```
if (scoreDifference + 1) >= 2 and leader >= game.winningScore do
  IO.puts "SOMEONE IS ABOUT TO WIN"
else
  IO.puts "NO-ONE IS ABOUT TO WIN"
end
{:reply, :ok, game}
```

(I've also moved the reply out of the `if` statement there, since it was the same across each.  If you wanted to do different things you could move it back in easy enough).

#### Use Pattern Matching to destructure the scores.

Assuming you are only ever expecting 2 entries in your score list, you could use pattern matching to extract the two scores.

```
[nextPlayer1, nextPlayer2] = game.score
```

I'm not adding 1 to the scores here, because this isn't neccesary to calculate the difference correctly. (It is neccesary to add one to check if someone has a winning score, but I'll come to that).

#### Simplifying the logic

You can just subtract one score from the other and then call `abs` on the result to get a positive number for the score difference:

```
scoreDifference = abs(nextPlayer1 - nextPlayer2)
```

Then you can find the leader with `Enum.max`:

```
leader = Enum.max(game.score)
```

#### Putting it all together

If you take all these improvements you might end up with something like:

```
[nextPlayer1, nextPlayer2] = game.score
scoreDifference = abs(nextPlayer1 - nextPlayer2)
leaderScore = Enum.max(game.score)
if scoreDifference + 1 >= 2 and (leaderScore + 1) >= game.winningScore do
  IO.puts "SOMEONE IS ABOUT TO WIN"
else
  IO.puts "NO-ONE IS ABOUT TO WIN"
end
{:reply, :ok, game}
```